# How to use jQuery table field result in if else condition?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have code of jQuery table where I need to use if else condition with table's last field m3 only result value & the condition is if result is greater than(>) 7 then display "FCL" below the table and if less than(<) 7 than "LCL" and if no result value in m3 column means table result of last field m3 is empty then nothing should display.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.pnm, .price, .subtot, .widtot, .perm, .tottot, .vol, .tot, .vols, .widths, .acts').prop('readonly', true);
        var $tblrows = $("#tblProducts tbody tr");

        $tblrows.each(function (index) {
            var $tblrow = $(this);
            $tblrow.find('.width, .carton, .perm').on('change', function () {
                var carton = $tblrow.find("[name=carton][type=number][min=0]").val();
                 var width = $tblrow.find("[name=width][type=number][min=0]").val();
                  var depth = $tblrow.find("[name=depth][type=number][min=0]").val()
                   var perm = $tblrow.find("[name=perm]").val();

                var subTotal =parseFloat(width*0.01, 10) * parseInt(carton, 10);
                var cartons =parseInt(carton, 10);
                var widths =parseInt(width, 10);

                 if (!isNaN(cartons)) {

                    $tblrow.find('.carton').val(cartons.toFixed(0));
                    var cartonTotal = 0;

                    $(".carton").each(function () {
                        var stval = parseInt($(this).val());
                        cartonTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
                    });

                    $('.cartontot').val(cartonTotal.toFixed(0));
                 }           
                 if (!isNaN(widths)) {

                    $tblrow.find('.width').val(widths.toFixed(0));
                    var widthTotal = 0;

                    $(".width").each(function () {
                        var stval = parseInt($(this).val());
                        widthTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
                    });

                    $('.widthtot').val(widthTotal.toFixed(0));
                 } 
                 if (!isNaN(subTotal)) {

                    $tblrow.find('.perm').val(subTotal.toFixed(5));
                    var grandTotal = 0;

                    $(".perm").each(function () {
                        var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
                        grandTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
                    });

                    $('.grdtot').val(grandTotal.toFixed(5));
                 }
            }); 
        }); 
    });
</script>

 <table id="tblProducts">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Products</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Cartons</td>
        <td><strong>Cm Width</td>
        <td><strong>M3</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product One" name="pnm" style="width:120px" /></td>
        <td ><input type="number" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" class="carton" value="0" name="carton" min="0" maxlength="5" style="width:70px"></td>
        <td><input type="number" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" class="width" value="0" min="0" name="width" maxlength="5" style="width:80px"/></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="perm" value="" name="perm" style="width:80px"/></td>
        <td class="error" style="color:red"></td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product Second" name="pnm" style="width:120px" /></td>
        <td ><input type="number" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" class="carton" value="0" name="carton" min="0" maxlength="5" style="width:70px"></td>
        <td><input type="number" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" class="width" value="0" min="0" name="width" maxlength="5" style="width:80px"/></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="perm" value="" name="perm" style="width:80px"/></td>
        <td class="error" style="color:red"></td>        
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="cartontot" value="" name="" style="width:70px" readonly/></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="grdtot" value="" name="" style="width:80px" readonly/></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already have the value to make your condition and it is in your `grandTotal` variable. so you must base your condition on THAT! and i add a row to your table to show the message there.

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td id="result">result: </td>
</tr>
```

and few line codes to display message.

```
if (grandTotal > 7) {
                    $('#result').html('FCL');
                } else if (grandTotal < 7) {
                    $('#result').html('LCL');
                }
```

and here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/en5kndkv/) .

Comment: yes thank you so much its working. thanks alot .
sir i have one another problem regarding this code if can answer me
and here is the problem  https://jsfiddle.net/LvzjLp06/14/

Comment: sir i have one another problem regarding this code if can answer me
and here is the problem  https://jsfiddle.net/LvzjLp06/17/

so the problem is here that the condition is applied on only height column with if else to show errors if condition will be wrong, But it gets issue that if i enter value that fulfill the heights condition then it gets reflects that error. so i need that  the condition should work with only height columns values not reflect with other columns values.can you please check sir. Please reply me asap thanks & Regards Inder

Comment: sorry i don't get the question. do you want your result to work only on height column change? @user7428613 or do you want to show message only on height column change? or ...?

Comment: yes sir the message that is displaying as "error with 20 STD and error with 40 STD" should only display on the height columns values not with any other columns values .

Comment: you can always put your condition to only look for height values. but you want to show your message on m3 change, is that right? if yes, then you should listen on m3 change NOT height change! @user7428613

Comment: sir actually the condition is applied on "tr" & "td.error"  bcz if i use height ion the condition then its not working it display me nothing. thats why i use condition with "tr" and "td.error". but i need the error messages should display only on the height column values not on cartons columns values & not on m3 columns values either the carton & m3 columns values are true for the condition bcz the condition should work for only height columns values to display the errors. i hope now with this i clearify my problem Regards Inder

Comment: i updated your fiddle here: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/LvzjLp06/18/) you can check it but i can't explain it here. look it and if you need more explanation let me now. @user7428613

Comment: sir thank you so much your code is working thanks alot sir  Regards Inder